# ERROR 1452: 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql, workbench

[image]

Im trying to make a simple data base but when i try to add data to either the album of song tables i get this error.

ERROR 1452: 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`newschema`.`songs`, CONSTRAINT `fk_Songs_Albums1` FOREIGN KEY (`Albums_AlbumId`) REFERENCES `Albums` (`AlbumId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
SQL Statement:
INSERT INTO `newschema`.`Songs` (`SongTitle`) VALUES ('Song1')

Im not sure if the structure is correct at all! but I am pretty desperate to get this working!
Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are using this query

```
INSERT INTO newschema.Songs (SongTitle) VALUES ('Song1')
```

So you insert a new song without a reference to any album. According to your schema that does not work. Every song must belong to an album.

So it should be at least something like this

```
INSERT INTO newschema.Songs (SongTitle, Albums_AlbumId) 
VALUES ('Song1', 1)
```

#### If you want such references being *optional* you have to allow NULLs in such columns.

Comment: ok. so I tried adding an album and..

ERROR 1452: 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`newschema`.`albums`, CONSTRAINT `fk_Albums_Musicians1` FOREIGN KEY (`Musicians_MusicianId`) REFERENCES `Musicians` (`MusicianId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
SQL Statement:
INSERT INTO `newschema`.`Albums` (`AlbumTitle`, `Musicians_MusicianId`) VALUES ('Album1', '1')

Comment: Also how do I change it so that a song does not have to belong to an album?

Comment: Same with the albums table. No album without a musican.

Comment: Extending a bit this answer, foreign key relationship means that your associated field has to have at least one of the values of the respecting field from the foreign table.

Comment: @user3075549: Change all the columns that should be optionally filled to allow nulls: You defined them currently as `NOT NULL` (remove the `NOT`)

Comment: Thank You! @juergen d
Made me very happy!
Im fairly sure my model is all wrong? But at least now i can add data. Thank you again!